# SpringBoot cannot upload large files after using Nignx

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload, upload

SpringBoot uses the Nginx reverse proxy and then opens the HTTPS protocol. If the file transfer exceeds 500KB, the data in the Request will not be received.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your nginx.conf and add this line into the server block:

```
server {
  client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

It means setting file size upload to 10M.

Comment: Currently 50M, upload size configuration is no problem, because it is completely normal under the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Maybe you should check SpringBoot file upload limits.